# fixed navigation with logo

Tags: html, css, sass, navbar

How can I create top navbar with logo on the left and nav on the right. When i use flexbox or display-inline-block it doesn't work.

```
<header id="header" class="header">
    <a class="logo" href="" title="">Essembli.</a>
    <nav class="top-nav">
        <ul class="site-nav">
            <li><a href="" title="">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Zespół</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Kompetencje</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Zarząd</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Kariera</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </header><!-- /header -->
```

My CSS:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    .logo {
        float: left;
    }
    .top-nav {  
        .site-nav {
            display: inline-block;
            li {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin-right: 15px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by using following approach 
I posted it in css not scss.

If you check fiddle it will more clear you that to how to get it.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0vmdrzb/)**

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
}

.logo {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.navigation {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    LOGO
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAV</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- /header -->
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur error excepturi optio quas delectus ea dolorum quam similique, architecto tempora adipisci eveniet atque esse doloribus aperiam! Facere cumque optio atque!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply that `display: inline-block;` to `.top-nav` since nav is a block element by default.

Added red/green background color to show you the block size, instead of using float, just use a div to wrap the logo

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/hfhjtp2y/

SCSS:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  .logowrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .top-nav {
    .site-nav {
      display: inline-block;
      li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
    }
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
}

.header .top-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.header .top-nav .site-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .top-nav .site-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.logowrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="logowrapper"><a class="logo" href="" title="">Essembli.</a></div>
  <nav class="top-nav">
    <ul class="site-nav">
      <li><a href="" title="">O nas</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Zespół</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Kompetencje</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Zarząd</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Kariera</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- /header -->
```